# Does an NSAttributedString in a UILabel ignore the label’s numberOfLines property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I need to increase the line spacing in a `UILabel`, so I’m using its `attributedString` to do so. Works fine, but it ignores the fact that I had also set the label’s `numberOfLines` to 2 – it only displays a single line, and truncates.

Any idea why this might be, what I can do about it, to still use two lines, but increase the spacing between them?

Comment: have you tried calling sizeToFit?

Comment: Yes, but because the label is in a UITableViewCell, this causes havoc if the cell is scrolled off and on-screen again since it keeps sizing smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the frame of your UILabel isn't big enough. Try increasing the height and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the label to the correct size for your number of lines by calling `sizeToFit` after setting the attributedText. To avoid the problem of the shrinking label in your table view cells, reset the frame of the label to some default size before setting the attributedText and calling sizeToFit. This will prevent the label from continuously shrinking.

Comment: That'd work too, I went with the height adjustment since it was needed elsewhere too. Many thanks, though!